# Как сделать так, чтобы нижний UIView был прижат к верхнему UIView при условии, что другие UIView имеют опцию hidden

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

Как сделать так, чтобы нижний `UIView` был прижат к верхнему `UIView` при условии, что другие `UIView` имеют опцию `hidden`?

И в нужный момент, чтобы опция `hidden` снималась и нижний `UIView` был все равно нижним.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Может быть с запозданием, но тем не менее. Похоже вы пытаетесь сделать так чтобы по наступлению определенного события между двумя UIView появились другие (прежде скрытые) UIView.

Возможно вам стоит присмотреться к [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview). В нем вместо UIView вы будете использовать [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell) со свойством [ContentView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview), на которых вы можете разместить интересующие вас элементы. Сами же ячейки нет смысла скрывать. Вы просто добавляете новые ячейки с помощью метода [insertRows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows) и можете даже указать анимацию для их появления. При добавлении и удалении элементов не забудьте использовать [beginUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates)/[endUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614890-endupdates) или [performBatchUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates)

Так-же ячейки можно удалить при помощи метода [deleteRows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614960-deleterows)